# Assistance with identifying this Javascript "script" object in my IVR

Tags: javascript

I am programming my IVR. I need to use the built in "script" object, which when inserted into the dialog flow in the IVR will execute JavaScript code. I need to create a simple JavaScript delay function, to delay the operation of another function in the IVR dialog, not JavaScript related at all. The IVR is a Windows based program and doesn't use Java or JavaScript for anything except in the "script object". There are a ton of examples of JavaScript delay timers code to use here on Stack. Problem is, whatever one I try to use in this IVR "script" object, nothing works. Would someone please try to identify what type of JavaScript code I need? Is it something specific to what I am showing here on my screenshot? This is existing code that I did not write, but it works. I don't know JavaScript programming and I only need one thing, a simple timer for the IVR dialog and I don't know what all the "sun net client" and "Java Lang System" and other stuff is in here. All I want to do is execute this delay code I found on Stack. What do I need as far as any specific syntax or whatever to make it work? The code below is what I want to use. The code that exists in the IVR "script object" is below the code I want to use. Is this some proprietary JavaScript code/syntax?

The IVR "script object" specifies this: JavaScript: The script resource is expected to be JavaScript 1.5 code, which is interpreted by Voxeo CXP Server.

```
What I want to use in my "script object"


var x = 1;
var y = null; // To keep under proper scope
setTimeout(function() {
x = x * 3 + 2;
y = x / 2;
}, 100);


Existing working code, had to delete some things cause it wouldn't format here but it is an example of how its written.



var url = new java.net.URL(
selfPayURL);
java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout ", 
java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout", "
var con = url.openConnection();
var in1 = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(
con.getInputStream()));
var readLine = in1.readLine();
finalResult = '';
while (readLine) {
finalResult += readLine;
readLine = in1.readLine();
}
in1.close();
con.disconnect();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These solutions you found are for JavaScript running on a webpage. With `setTimeout` you're asking the JavaScript engine to call a function after a certain amount of time. For example, maybe you want to update a value on the page every few seconds while a user views it. But in that case, of course the user is free to browse to the next page or hit the back button at any time - they don't have to wait for the timer to "go off".

When your IVR is running your script, the only instruction is to "set the timer" (but not to wait for the timer to "go off"), then there's no more instructions and so the script finishes and the IVR moves on to the next form/prompt. It sounds like JavaScript doesn't have a simple way to wait on the timer (perhaps you could do it with Promises and `await`, but that requires a later version of JavaScript than yours).

I haven't used CXP, but I understand that it's a tool for generating VXML. To get a pause in VXML you would just add a break tag to a prompt. As in:

```
<prompt>
    <break duration="5000ms"/>
</prompt>
```

And then transition to the waiting phase by collecting some input (even if there's no grammar, and you just expect a timeout).

Comment: Now I understand.Yes, when programming the IVR in Eclipse it creates VXML behind the scenes and I can easily edit that. Problem is, I tried doing the prompt thing playing a wave file of like 5 seconds, thinking I was going to get 5 seconds of delay between dialog steps, but it didn't work.The step I need the delay in is just before the "script" object does a web call to my PHP server to fetch inbound text message. If no text message is present on PHP side, I need the time delay to fetch again till text msg is there. With prompt, as delay CXP just hammers PHP relentless, no delay in dialog.

Comment: But perhaps I could add the break tag as you say to the prompt I had created for all of this. I will try it.

Comment: You need to collect input in your loop as well. If you just loop around prompt tags, all you're doing is queueing more prompts without actually playing them or waiting for them to play. If you add an input, even one that you expect just to timeout, then the prompt (which could be just a break) will play before making another request.

Comment: And that is exactly what it looks like is going on in the logs, the prompts continually get queued as the script object keeps hammering PHP with web calls. Makes total sense to create a dummy input object. I will have to have a noinput/noanswer after 5 seconds branch back to the original loop. I wish I could make an expression object do a timer thing. Its kind of crude doing input objects with no input as delays. Thanks!